# GAE: MQTT broker

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mqtt, iot, moquette

So I was wondering if it's possible to run a MQTT broker on the Google App Engine platform? 
Couldn't find any information about it (or maybe I might be using the wrong keywords).

I've got my GAE running on Java so I'd like to go into direction of running the MQTT broker on GAE using a backend.

**EDIT:**
Did some further research and it seems Moquette is running on Java. Does someone have experience running Moquette on the GAE?

**EDIT2:**
Ok, it seems the examples of Moquette are running using an OSGi container, which is unavailble in GAE. Looking for a script to start this server on GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MQTT is protocol on top of TCP. In order to run MQTT server, one needs to be able to open a listening socket. Those are still not supported on normal AppEngine instances.

Note: GAE backends have been replaced: [now you just have](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Instance_scaling_and_class) automatic scaled (aka frontend) instances and manual scaled (aka backend) instances.

Back to your problem: [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/managed-vms/) have most of the benefits of GAE (access to services), but run a full JVM, which allows listening sockets.

Comment: Could a possible solution be: running a broker on a seperate server and defining an MQTT client as backend in my GAE application, which then forwards data into my datastore? Am I right that this client won't be needing the listening socket?

Comment: If GAE is a MQTT client and it only sends notifications, then this would probably work.

Comment: Slightly off topic but can just the MQTT client be run on a backend (now service?). This is for e.g. to listen to a publicly available broker.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Moquette would also be the [HiveMQ](http://www.hivemq.com) broker, it also runs on Java and can be easily installed. All the documentation is available [here](http://www.hivemq.com/documentation/).
We haven't tested it on GAE yet, but if you have any problems running it, you could ask in the support forum.

Update: If Peter Knego is right, then HiveMQ or any other MQTT broker won't work on GAE.

Full disclose: I'm working for the company, who develops HiveMQ.

Cheers,

Christian

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'm still comparing different options :)

Answer (score 1):

@Peter Knego is definitely right, and all i would add to his answer is that,

If you manage to configure you application to use a custom Runtime on the Managed Vms of Appengine and Compute Engine,

then you will be able to run you MQTT brooker perfectly sound and well.

As long as you define a fire wall to allow a tcp connection at the port which your broker is listening from.

By default the ports are blocked for security reasons.